# does performing a `get` on a queryset evaluates the whole queryset or just one element of queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

pseudocode:

```py
class TestModel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField()
    b = models.CharField()

qs = Model.objects.filter(a="something") # returns qs containing 5 objects

obj = qs.get(b='something_else') # evaluates the queryset and hits the db

obj2 = qs.get(b='something_else_2') # evaluates again? hits db again?
```

Now while assigning to `obj2`, will it hit db again? or even will it hit db while assigning to `obj`?

Comment: `qs` is not evaluated: querysets are lazy and thus are only evaluated when you want to "consume" the queryset. In this scenario, it will hit the database twice, each time for a `.get(..)` request, and will each time fetch a single record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QuerySet`s are lazy, that means that your `qs` will *not* be evaluated, unless you somehow "consume" it (for example by iterating over it, call `len(…)`, `str(…)` on it, etc.).

You use `qs` as a basic queryset to make two queries with the two `.get(…)` calls. These will each result in a *single* query that aims to fetch a single record. Django will thus make two queries, one with:

```
SELECT model.a, model.b FROM model WHERE a=something and b=something_else
```

and:

```
SELECT model.a, model.b FROM model WHERE a=something and b=something_else_2
```

First constructing a common queryset `qs` will thus have *no* performance impact, but can for example be more convenient in terms of software design.